# Edge and primefaces not loading resources

Tags: jsf, primefaces, microsoft-edge

I have several applications published using Primefaces (versions 5-11), and apparently since the last update of Microsoft Edge (115.0.1901.183 - July 21 - default settings and no plugins), the resources aren't properly loaded in this browser (images and javascripts), so the users are reporting that they cannot browse for different reasons (scripts not found, buttons hidden because they don't have background, etc).

I'm doing some tests and the images report the error JSF1064 (cannot load the resource), but it is the only error I can see.

In chrome it keeps working as intended.

Any idea of what might be causing this?

EDIT: Apparently the problem is intermittent, although it fails the most of the times.

EDIT2: Enabling internet explorer compatibility fixes the problem, but this is a temporal solution.

EDIT3: When the page takes longer to load is when Edge cuts the connection, otherwise it works (that's what makes it intermittent).

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. I've tested on of our applications on Edge last week and it was working perfectly.

Comment: Every app that we have (more than 11) have different versions of primefaces, spring, etc, I don't know if I will be able to create a reproducible example so easily. I made the question to find out if we are the only ones suffering this problem or somebody else has also noticed. Anyway I will try to create a basic project to reproduce it.

Comment: Please use https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test to create a reproducer.

Comment: Also check your corporate settings in Edge or plugins that may be affecting this.

Comment: I'm doing tests with a fresh Edge with default settings and no plugins, in a network outside our corporate one, and a fresh installation of Tomcat 8.5 also with default settings. I'm still working on the example, although slowly because all this mess.

Comment: I'm still working on the example and it seems that if the page takes slightly longer to load, it is when Edge cuts the connection, however if the page is very light, it works without problems. Also we noticed that enabling Internet Explorer compatibility mode fixes the problem (but this is not a solution).

Answer (score 1):

Today Microsft released a new version of the browser (115.0.1901.188) and now everything works again, so if you are having this problem, simply update your browser to the newer version.